# How to display the exact 10 digit numerical value in a text using plsql?

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
SELECT carddetails 
FROM cc_emp_card 
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE ( carddetails,'[[:digit:]]{10}?([^[:digit:]])');
```

Current output:

```
FT 6820220419001794 xxx asdfwf 2 BIM 2022
FT 6820220419001796 xsdjcc jcw 2 BIM 2022
FT 6820220419001796 ajscbjk , c dk2 BIM 2022
000006650445/Business Meals (Staff with Externals)
5010083131,1234567890
1234567890
5010009921 dcbjwk ft 4959 29.04
5010018300 Dmdbchbk jdkjw 11 del 09.05
5000630739 dbcwbdj FT 9/001 DEL 13.05
5010015146 mnwd chjw    FT 4 DEL 29.04.22
```

Expected output:

```
5010083131,1234567890
1234567890
5010009921 dcbjwk ft 4959 29.04
5010018300 Dmdbchbk jdkjw 11 del 09.05
5000630739 dbcwbdj FT 9/001 DEL 13.05
5010015146 mnwd chjw    FT 4 DEL 29.04.22
```

Comment: Expected Result: It should display only 10 length number in field
5010009921 dcbjwk ft 4959 29.04 
5010018300 Dmdbchbk jdkjw 11 del 09.05
5000630739 dbcwbdj FT 9/001 DEL 13.05 
5010015146 mnwd chjw FT 4 DEL 29.04.22

Comment: `Example data:

5010009921 dcbjwk ft 4959 29.04  
5010018300 Dmdbchbk jdkjw 11 del 09.05  
5000630739 dbcwbdj FT 9/001 DEL 13.05  
5010015146 mnwd chjw    FT 4 DEL 29.04.22  
5010015146  
5010015146  
5010015146, 5010015146  
FT 6820220419001794 xxx asdfwf 2 BIM 2022
FT 6820220419001796 xsdjcc jcw 2 BIM 2022
FT 6820220419001796 ajscbjk , c dk2 BIM 2022

Expected result:

5010009921 dcbjwk ft 4959 29.04
5010018300 Dmdbchbk jdkjw 11 del 09.05
5000630739 dbcwbdj FT 9/001 DEL 13.05
5010015146 mnwd chjw    FT 4 DEL 29.04.22
5010015146
5010015146
5010015146, 5010015146`

Answer (score 0):

You should *anchor* those digits to the beginning of the string:

```
SQL> SELECT carddetails
  2    FROM cc_emp_card
  3   WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (carddetails, '^[[:digit:]]{10}?([^[:digit:]])');
                                       |
                                      this!

CARDDETAILS
--------------------------------------------------
5010009921 dcbjwk ft 4959 29.04
5010018300 Dmdbchbk jdkjw 11 del 09.05
5000630739 dbcwbdj FT 9/001 DEL 13.05
5010015146 mnwd chjw    FT 4 DEL 29.04.22

SQL>
```

Comment: That's unreadable, sorry. Edit the original question and post that info there. Use [CODE] tags to preserve formatting.

Comment: could you help me with new output ?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. You posted two more sets of unreadable data, I can't do anything with that.